# ProcMon hide GUI

Tags: process-monitoring, procmon

I have to track down an error and I want to run procmon on several computers automatically to catch that error. My problem is, that procmon shows a GUI even if the logged on user isn't the same as the user running procmon.

I need to know how to completely hide procmon. Otherwise it would irritate my users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used cmdow in the past for similar situations, the only issue is that many Antivirus programs now flag this as a "virus" though it is not by any means. So you will have to add an exception.

> cmdow /run /hid procmon.exe

Of course the above assumes that these files are placed in your %windir%\system32 directory

http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try that when I'm working on that error again and will let you know if it worked.